# Figure out which region of sudoku the item is in

Tags: graph-theory, sudoku

Suppose we have hyper sudoku.

[image]

In the dark gray areas, we can have 1-9 only once. Therefore, when solving a sudoku graph, I need to figure out what region to look over, to see if any repeats occur.

What is the mathematical expression I can use to find this "region"?

For example, given that the top left $1$ is $(0,0)$, the circled $9$ is at $(2,2)$, where row is $2$, col is $2$.

This region spans from $(1,1)$ to $(3,3)$.

Similarly, the $1$ circled in the bottom left located at $(6,5)$ is spanning region $(5,5)$ to $(7,7)$.

This is clear from visual, but for a mathematical expression, what can be used to figure out the region?

I assume mod must be used, but cannot think of the expression that would work for all cases.

Comment: Wouldn't the circled 9 be at (2,2)? It's on the diagonal so I don't see how it could be (2,3)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a problem this small it is probably easier to just list the four regions.  The bottom left would be row in $[5,7]$ column in $[1,3]$

If you want a fancy looking math formula or have a larger grid it would be $[4k+1,4k+3]$ in each direction.

Comment: What is $k$ here? For example if I have $(2,2)$, how does $4k+1$ give me boundary?

Comment: $k$ is any natural including $0$.  The example $(2,2)$  is in the interval $[4\cdot 0+1,4\cdot 0+3]=[1,3]$.  If you check, if you use that in both dimensions you get the upper left gray square.  If you use $k=1$ for the horizontal and $k=0$ for the vertical you get the lower left gray square.